# How to add a new then after fetch has run

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, fetch-api

I have a method that runs a fetch request and then saves the result or error like this:

```
saveTema() {
 this.gateway.editTema(this.state.tema)
  .then(tema => {
    this.setState({
      tema,
      error: null,
      isDirty: false,
    });
  })
  .catch(httpOrOtherError => {
    if (httpOrOtherError.status) {
      if (httpOrOtherError.status === 400) {
        httpOrOtherError.json().then(result => {
          const serverValidationfailures = 
          this.transformValideringsfeil(result.valideringsfeil);
          this.setState({
            error: {
              valideringsfeil: {...serverValidationfailures},
            },
            showActivationDialog: false,
          })
       });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          error: {httpError: {status: httpOrOtherError.status, statusText: httpOrOtherError.statusText}},
          showActivationDialog: false,
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        error: {fetchReject: {message: httpOrOtherError.message}},
        showActivationDialog: false,
      })
    }
  })
}
```

And this is the fetch request itself:

```
editTema(tema) {
    return fetch(
      this.temaUrl(tema.id),
      {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(tema)
      })
      .then(res => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
          }
          throw res;
        }
      );
  }
```

I would like to run this method from another one, and check if everything went ok with this method and based on that do further actions. Something like this:

```
this.saveTema().then(() => {
  this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/tema',
    state: {
      successMessage: `Tema ${this.state.tema.id} ble oppdatert`,
    }
}}));
```

But, this is of course wrong, I am not sure how can I do this, to run some code after the fetch handling of the fetch request has finished. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Is that actually wrong? It’ll do something if you return the promise (`return this.gateway.editTema(this.state.tema)…`) in the other function. Maybe that something will be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
saveTema() {
  return this.gateway.editTema(this.state.tema)
    ...
```

Return the promise and then you'll be able to do exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Return the `editThema` result after setting up the handlers:

```
saveTema() {
    let prom = this.gateway.editTema(this.state.tema)
    prom.then(tema => {
        // .. success handling code
    })
    .catch(httpOrOtherError => {
        // .. error handling code
    })
    return prom;
}
```

Now you can call your function exactly like you wanted to.

Comment: `this.gateway.editTema...` is already a promise, so you don't need to wrap it in `new Promise()` to return it. You also don't need to declare `saveTema` as `async` since it is just returning a promise, not `await`ing anything and it explicitly returns a promise.

Comment: My mistake. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by two approaches

1. Using `async/await`
2. Using `native Promise`

**1. async/await way**

**userController.js**

```
const userUtils = require('./userUtils');

const userCtr = {};

userCtr.searchUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userName } = req.query;
    const result = await userUtils.searchUser(userName);
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(err.code).json({ error: err.error });
  }
};

module.exports = userCtr;
```

**userUtils.js**

```
const userUtils = {};

userUtils.searchUser = async (userName) => {
  try {
    if (userName) {
      // ...Do some cool stuff
      const result = [];
      return result;
    }
    const errorObj = { code: 400, error: 'ERR_VALID_PARAM' };
    throw errorObj;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
};

module.exports = userUtils;
```

**2. Promise way**
**userController.js**

```
const userUtils = require('./userUtils');

const userCtr = {};

userCtr.searchUser = (req, res) => {
  const { userName } = req.query;
  userUtils.searchUser(userName)
    .then((result) => {
      return res.status(200).json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(err.code).json({ error: err.error });
    });
};

module.exports = userCtr;
```

**userUtils.js**

```
const userUtils = {};

userUtils.searchUser = (userName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (userName) {
            // ...Do some cool stuff
            const result = [];
            return resolve(result);
        } else {
            const error = { code: 400, error: 'Please provide valid data!' }
            return reject(error);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = userUtils;
```

In both approaches you can hold further execution (in both approach `Promise` are used directly or indirectly), In a second approach you can achieve by `.then().catch()` whereas in the first approach just you need to put a keyword `await` and put `async` on your function, I suggest you to use `async/await`. Because when you need to wait for the completion of more than 3 promises and yo go with `Native Promise` then your code will be so messy like `.then().then().then()` Whereas in a first approach you just need to put a keyword `await` on starting of your function, Using `async/await` approach your code will neat and clean and easily understandable and easy to debug.